# if statement with conditions longer than 1

Tags: r

Code(psuedo)

```
x = c('Gender','Employee Status')
y = c('Gender','Employee Status','Tenure')
if (!(x %in% y)){do this}
else(do this)
```

I know that `if` isn't vectorized and ifelse is but ifelse gives me some errors. with functions I use. Is there a way to make an `if` vectorized to accept multiple inputs like above? the Do this and do that are a series of steps.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Perhaps `!any(x %in% y)` or `all(...)` is what you're after?

Comment: Ahh !any was it. I was using it wrong when I tried that before. thanks!

Comment: you can also use `sum(!(x %in% y))` which will return the number of `TRUE`s and then consider a condition like `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

You could use set notation to check if `X` is within `Y`

```
# Setup
x <- c('Gender','Employee Status')
y <- c('Gender','Employee Status','Tenure')

# Check X in Y
if (identical(setdiff(x, y), character(0))) {
    print("All of X in Y")
} else {
    print("Not all of X in Y")
}
```